# in pytorch, cuda.is_availbale(), but every operation fails with out of memory

Tags: linux, gpu, pytorch

I've set up a new virtual machine (on GCP) with a K80 GPU on Ubuntu 16.
Followed [installation instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=debnetwork) for the CUDA toolkit 9.1

nvidia-smi returns correctly:
NVIDIA-SMI 390.12                 Driver Version: 390.12
...

in pytorch, cuda.is_available() returns True,
but any operation fails:

```
torch.randn(10).cuda() ==>

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at /opt/conda/conda-
bld/pytorch_1512378422383/work/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.cu:58
```

What am I missing in the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. Never mind I had to restart the machine for the drivers to reload.

Comment: I am using google colaboratory. I have restarted runtime many times but still facing the same issue. `RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at`

Answer (score 0):

1. sometimes the GPU memory is occupied by the previous operation to free up the memory the IDE kernel (spyder/spyder3) can be restarted or restart your PC.
2. try the code with **sudo** command if you are using Ubuntu.

hope it works for you as well.